# printing the data from a mysql query with a shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I'm new to shell scripting and relational databases. What I am trying to accomplish is writing a shell script to check the MySQL database and print the contents of my query. The big gap in my understanding is assigning the data to a variable for my echo statement. The goal is to print the changes made to the database. I do not have any examples because I really don't know where to start. Everything online I've seen is not making the connection in my head.

Comment: If you know how to type the commands in at the prompt, then you just put those commands into a file and execute the shell on that file.

Comment: I edited my original question. Thank you for the  quick response. I need to print the changes made to the database by my shell script.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you mean. What do you mean by "print the changes made"? Changes made since what point in time? How are the changes logged and where?

Comment: When `getdata` is a script connecting to the database and showing data at your terminal, you can store the output in a variable with `mydata=$(getdata)` and show the data with `echo "${mydata}"`.